# bugzilla-IRC integration

Tags: debian, irc, bugzilla

I have a bugzilla instance. I also have an IRC channel. I need a bot which can spew out any changes happening in bugzilla.

The bot should prompt or tell when any action from :-

a. Raising a bug

b. Comments on the bug

c. Resolution changes on the bug (confirmed,Will not fix,RESOLVED-fixed etc.) are also shared.

I looked around and found bugzilla-linker, see https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Addons but neither the code or the binary is there anywhere. Can somebody share an alternative of that if it exists ?

Update - In addition it would be nice if it is able to have it log conversations on the channel as well, kinda channel logging.

@Mikel did find those but they don't seem to have the logging feature.

It would be nice if one bot has it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong section of the page.

[The Bot section](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Addons#IRC_Bots) mentions BZBot, MozBot, and others.

Comment: thank you. I am using eggdrop 1.6 for logging so if you know of a bot which can do both or has both modules and is FOSS (as in copyleft-license) would be great. Your answer is close but my question, query has changed, sorry.